# Subtract values from columns, based on groupings

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a data frame in R in the following format:

```
Treatment    Sample   Time_point   M1
        A         1            0   0.12
        A         2            0   0.45
        A         3            0   0.35
        A         1            1   0.76
        A         2            1   0.45
        A         3            1   0.41
        A         1            2   0.94
        A         2            2   0.55
        A         3            2   0.44
```

etc. There are 5 different treatments, 3 samples, and 10 time points. There are also about 50 columns of various measurements, with unrelated names - I only show the first of these, M1, here.

For each of these 50 measurements I would like to subtract the value that they hold at time zero, from all the subsequent time points. As an example, M1 would subsequently look like this:

```
 M1
 0
 0
 0
 0.64
 0
 0.06
 0.82
 0.10
 0.09
```

I can't figure out how to do this. I started by extracting the Time-point Zero values, making a repeating sequence of them, and then subtracting them. However, I've only been able to get this to work one column at a time, which is a bit convoluted. I wonder if there is a way to do it within a pipe, using group_by and mutate to change the values of each column, but couldn't figure out a way to specify the values I need to subtract.

Comment: for data.table specifically, this question was asked in a more general form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794449/data-table-apply-function-over-groups-with-reference-to-set-value-in-each-group/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d$M1 - ave(d$M1, d$Sample, d$Treatment, FUN = function(x) x[1])
#[1] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.64 0.00 0.06 0.82 0.10 0.09
```

For more than one column, try

```
nm = c("M1")  #Add column names here
sapply(nm, function(s){
    d[[s]] - ave(d[[s]], d$Sample, d$Treatment, FUN = function(x) x[1])
})
#        M1
# [1,] 0.00
# [2,] 0.00
# [3,] 0.00
# [4,] 0.64
# [5,] 0.00
# [6,] 0.06
# [7,] 0.82
# [8,] 0.10
# [9,] 0.09
```

The `tidyverse` equivalent will probably be

```
d %>% group_by(Sample, Treatment) %>% mutate_at(nm, function(x) x - x[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - my table has around 50 other columns to the right of M1, which I want to treat in the same way.  Is there a way to adapt this to apply to all of them, without copying the line 50 times?

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`, you can try:

```
df %>%
 group_by_at(1:2) %>%
 mutate(M1 = M1 - first(M1))

  Treatment Sample Time_point    M1
  <chr>      <int>      <int> <dbl>
1 A              1          0  0   
2 A              2          0  0   
3 A              3          0  0   
4 A              1          1  0.64
5 A              2          1  0   
6 A              3          1  0.06
7 A              1          2  0.82
8 A              2          2  0.1 
9 A              3          2  0.09
```

Or to perform this operation on all columns from column 4:

```
df %>%
 group_by_at(1:2) %>%
 mutate_at(4:length(.), ~ . - first(.))
```

If you need to arrange the data first:

```
df %>%
 arrange_at(1:3) %>%
 group_by_at(1:2) %>%
 mutate(M1 = M1 - first(M1))
```

Or for multiple columns:

```
df %>%
 arrange_at(1:3) %>%
 group_by_at(1:2) %>%
 mutate_at(4:length(.), ~ . - first(.))
```

Comment: It would be prudent to `arrange` the data by time to guarantee that the `first` point is the one at time 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can join with a subset of the data having time 0, and use data.table's update join functionality. Note that this updates the original data.frame rather than creating a new one.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[df[Time_point == 0], on = .(Treatment, Sample), 
   M1 := M1 - i.M1]

#    Treatment Sample Time_point   M1
# 1:         A      1          0 0.00
# 2:         A      2          0 0.00
# 3:         A      3          0 0.00
# 4:         A      1          1 0.64
# 5:         A      2          1 0.00
# 6:         A      3          1 0.06
# 7:         A      1          2 0.82
# 8:         A      2          2 0.10
# 9:         A      3          2 0.09
```

**For multuple columns:**

create example data and vector of column names

```
set.seed(2019)
df[, M2 := sample(nrow(df))]

cols <- grep('^M', names(df), value = T)
```

Subtract the time 0 values

```
df[df[Time_point == 0], on = .(Treatment, Sample), 
   (cols) := setDT(mget(cols)) - mget(paste0('i.', cols))][]

#    Treatment Sample Time_point   M1 M2
# 1:         A      1          0 0.00  0
# 2:         A      2          0 0.00  0
# 3:         A      3          0 0.00  0
# 4:         A      1          1 0.64 -3
# 5:         A      2          1 0.00 -5
# 6:         A      3          1 0.06  2
# 7:         A      1          2 0.82  2
# 8:         A      2          2 0.10  2
# 9:         A      3          2 0.09 -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Although IceCreamToucan's answer is nice, I find it a bit overcomplicated. With `data.table`, in a similar fashion to `dplyr`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,M1 := M1 - M1[0], by = .(Treatment, Sample)]
```

For multiple columns:

```
cols <- grep('^M', names(df), value = T)
df[,c(cols) := lapply(.SD,function(x){x- x[1]}),.SDcols = cols]
```